# How to do this integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{itx-2|x|} \ dx $$

Comment: Before @mickep shared their beautiful answer (hint), what did you attempt yourself? Please remember to show your effort in future questions.

Comment: Hi . I decompose into the $-\infty $, 0 and 0,  $ +\infty  $ interval to integrate but do not know how to think of the value at infty of the primitive since there is an $i$ involved.

Comment: Ok. As a note, include your attempts and workings out in your questions so other users can answer appropriately :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when you have an absolute value, you can divide into cases. Here, you could write
$$
\int_{-\infty} e^{itx-2|x|}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{itx+2x}\,dx+\int_0^{+\infty}e^{itx-2x}\,dx.
$$
Then you just find a primitive function and insert limits.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer . I have a problem. How do I deal with the primitive at infinity when there is an $i$ invoved.

Comment: Well, not much happens, in the first case you have a primitive $e^{itx+2x}/(it+2)$. As $x$ tends to $-\infty$ the exponential term vill tend to $0$.